# Time difference google calendar and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, date, google-calendar-api

The php code to set utc--

```
$timestr = '2012-01-19T22:00:00.000-08:00';
    $date = new DateTime($timestr);

    $tz = new DateTimeZone('UTC');
    $date->setTimezone($tz);

    foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {

 foreach ($event->when as $when) {

echo $when->startTime;

}

}
```

Now the js

```
var isoDate = new Date().toISOString();
```

The result :

```
> Google Calendar -> 2013-06-14T23:38:00.000+02:00 && 
> JS -> 2013-06-15T10:42:50.812Z
```

Now what I need is to compare both times, to show some notification of my own. But as the results are different it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [date.js](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/) (or time.js) to help you with the Javascript time:

*Using date.js:*
-- note that their example has a typo, citing <s>ISO 6801</s>, instead of the correct ISO 8601

```
// Convert date to ISO 8601 string
new Date().toISOString()
// Returns ISO 8601 string of date converted to it's UTC value.
// "2007-10-31T16:18:00Z"
```

Comment: Thank you. But still the dates are not similar. I have updated my question. I have already set the PHP timezone as UTC. So shouldn't it give me the same time?